# Counting the amount of decimal places from a text file and identifying whitespaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of numbers separated by commas and I want my output or I want it to return the amount of decimal places from each number from each line of my text file and I also want it to say "white space found" within that line if there's a space in between the numbers and comma and if not then I want it to say " No error found" The code I have check if the number has more or less than two decimal places and/or a whitespace in between the numbers then it is INVALID. If there is no whitespace and it has two decimal places then it is VALID( I thought maybe that might help somehow?)

```
#Open the files
with open('file.txt') as fp:

    #Extract out non-empty lines from file
    lines = [line for line in fp.readlines() if line.strip()]
    res = []

    #Iterate over the lines
    for idx, line in enumerate(lines):

        #Number is valid if it doesn't start with a whitespace, has a decimal part and the decimal part is two digits long
        res = ['VALID' if not item.startswith(' ') and '.' in item and len(item.split('.')[1]) == 2 else 'INVALID' for item in line.split(',')]

        #Print the result
        print("Line {}: {}".format(idx+1, ' '.join(res)))
```

Return the number of decimal Places for each number read in the line and separate each of them by a tab. Also, if there is a space between the number and comma then return whitespace found, if there is no whitespace then return no error found

From a text file example

```
1.1,1.023, 1.45

1.1,1.023,1.45
```

Expected:

Return

```
Line 1: 1”tab”3”tab”2”tab”white space found

Line 2: 1”tab”3”tab”2”tab”no error found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.txt` is containing:

```
1.1,1.023, 1.45

1.1,1.023,1.45
```

The script:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    line_no = 1
    for line in f_in:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        print('Line {}:'.format(line_no), end=' ')
        print('\t'.join(str(len(g)) for g in re.findall(r'\d+\.?(\d+)?', line)   ), end='\t')
        print('white space found' if re.findall(r',(\s+)\d', line) else 'no error found')
        line_no += 1
```

Prints:

```
Line 1: 1   3   2   white space found
Line 2: 1   3   2   no error found
```

Comment: Great! Quick question, what if there's a whole number...wouldn't that be 0 decimal places?? It doesn't read a whole number

Comment: @Slashx43 I updated my answer, now it prints `0` when there's whole number

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much

Comment: Ive been trying to find how to detect for tab returns as well. I would've thought it would be re,findall(r',( \t+)\d', line) but it doesn't work. Also,  at the last line, if there is no carriage return after then I need it to say "No carriage return found" Not sure if it's re.findall(r',(\n+)\d', line)

Comment: @Slashx43 You can make another question, where you write your sample input and expected output. These comments are not suitable place for it.